# I need a library much like Java's GregorianCalendar but in C or C++

Tags: c++, gregorian-calendar

While this might not seem exactly like a programming question, non-programmers won't know what I'm talking about. If you can suggest a more appropriate stack* forum, I'll happily ask there, but I think this is my best shot.

libical is a good start, but it doesn't have anywhere near what I need.
I do not want to reinvent tons of calendar math functions if they already exist, and I also do not want to suck in boost or roguewave or anything like that just to do calendaring.

Any suggestions? I've looked and looked and found nothing, but my google-fu isn't supreme.

Comment: When C/C++ has not standardised Date type (or not promoted), hard to say. What "dialect" of C/C++ do You use? MFC, ancient Borland, Qt,  other

Comment: @JacekCz: I think the word you're looking for is "Framework".

Comment: you refuse boost ... well, ok ... but then it is incumbent on you in any case to tell us what "tons of calendar math functions" libical is missing that you want ... or do you expect us to compare the java api with the libical api and guess?

Comment: @Mooing Dock agree. And "framework" usually re-implement or over-implement wheel (not standardised in C/C++, or when standard doesn't meet acceptance) , like String type, sometimes Date, business numeric. containers etc....

Comment: Sorry if my question didn't include enough detail. I'm writing a portable C and C++ application that has to run on linux and osx and windows. GregorianCalendar allows you to do things like add variable number of any unit to the object and it adjusts itself accordingly. It allows you to do things like take 3/31/2016 and add 1 month and it will come up with the correct date. That's the kind of math I'm talking about.

Comment: @stu hard to believe You dont use any library, framework etc...

Comment: What about [ICU Date/Time Services](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime)?

Comment: @jacekCz Welcome to the world of software that you write and know it works. Everybody else uses frameworks, and everybody else's software breaks and nobody knows why. When my software breaks I can fix it. I am a dinosaur and this is how dinosaurs do it.

Comment: @Bob__ I hadn't heard of that, I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: @PeterT - I don't actually see that implication anywhere ..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By rejecting Boost you're rejecting a library that's had not only extensive design review but also probably extensive testing by people who you can guess (hope) have experience with the picky picky details of datetime calculations.

But ok, I can actually understand the desire to avoid Boost if possible.

But you're entering a world where you have even more responsibility than usual to validate the design and implementation.

That said, this library looks like its promising for your purposes: [Howard Hinnant's date library on github](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) (see also his pages [here for a man page](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html) and [here for a description of the algorithms used](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html). I have not used it, of course.  (If you do take this suggestion, please report back here, so we'll all know about this library's worth.)

Comment: Bless you. I'll check it out. thanks.

Comment: @Stu - It's for C++ 11, BTW, as it is built on `<chrono>`.

Comment: It looks really good so far... Thanks A LOT.

Comment: GAR! It compiles and I was writing my first test program when I saw that it doesn't include time, just calendar days, which admittedly helps, but being able to do math on time is required also. Thanks though, maybe I can work with this.

Comment: @stu -  Well, he emphasizes throughout that it is built on `<chrono>` and in fact is using standard timepoints.  So don't you get time calculations for free from that?  BTW - I can see that this question is getting flagged as off topic.  Perhaps you can figure out how to migrate it to Programmers or to Software Recommendations?

Comment: @stu (you might have to convert from this library's timepoint (perhaps based on units of 1 day) to a timepoint based on seconds but `<chrono>` can do that for you.)

Comment: Re: "doesn't include time":  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html#time_of_day

Comment: @HowardHinnant firstly your library is awesome. But something I might need to do, is add 260,000 seconds, so it's not just time of day, I'd need it to figure out how many days had gone by and adjust the time object appropriately.

Comment: @davidbak ahhh, that was part of my question, what other stack* site was available. I didn't know that one existed, thanks.

Comment: @stu:  Like this? http://pastebin.com/Cp7nTQwd

Comment: @HowardHinnant - god I love the "modern" C++

Comment: Yes like that. I didn't catch that in my first pass through, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the best answer is going to be Boost's [`date_time`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html) library.  Though you should see if your C++ framework has something already first.  Always try to match your framework when you can.